# How to divide a bigdecimal object coming from OCI8 recordset?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal, oci8

```
def main()

  myDB=DB.new('myUser','myPass','myDB')
  record = myDB.handle().select_one('select count(*) from things')
  printf "%10d" % record

end
```

main()
result:
30008428

I want to divide this value by 24 to create batches which will be executed every hour.
This is the pretty print result:

```
[#<BigDecimal:ac2fdf94,'0.30008428E8',8(12)>]
```

I'm pretty confused on how to achieve that.
As I understand it "record" is an array with a BigDecimal object in it.
I tried to do
record[0].div(24) that didn't work either.
record.div(24) also didn't work.

Since I've spent quite a bit of time figuring it out now, I feel like I need to turn to the community for a little bit of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your question, I would expect `record[0].div(24)` to produce a result e.g. `1250351`. Could you clarify "didn't work", including the actual code you tried, the result you expected, and the result you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DBI::Handle#select_one` method (which I imagine is what must be hidden behind your `DB` module) returns a single record from the database. Because this one record could potentially contain several fields, it returns the record as an array. In this case there is only a single column - the count - so that count value is in `record[0]`.

I guess by *"pretty print"* you mean the output from `p record`, which is debugging output rather than just pretty printing. It is the equivalent of `puts record.inspect`. In this case it shows a *single* object (everything within `#<...>`) inside an array (the `[...]`).

In the case of `BigDecimal` objects, `inspect` returns a string giving the class name, *BigDecimal*; the address in hex, *ac2fdf94*; the current value as a string, *0.30008428E8*; and the current (maximum) number of significant figures, *8 (12)*.

The short answer to your question is that you probably want to write

```
count = record[0].to_i
```

and use `count` thereafter, which is a normal `Fixnum`, so your division looks like

```
per_hour = count / 24.0
```

A value of 30,008,428 is well within the maximum `Fixnum` value, which depends on your machine word size but is probably 2<sup>30</sup> or over one billion. And even if you exceed that value, Ruby will - mostly silently - convert to a `Bignum` for you so nothing bad should happen.